# java primitive type array object or not?

Tags: java, arrays

Consider the following program:

```
int[] arr= new int[2];
.....
System.out.println(arr.length);
```

In JLS we read that object in java is instance of class or array. 
But, we see here array of primitive type. So, `int[2]` is an object too. But, how it was achieved? It was sth like `int=>Integer`, or `int[]=>Integer[]` or
something else? And by the way, where it resides? In heap or in stack?

Comment: An array of something is completely different than the something. i.e., an array of int is not the same thing as an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java you only have primitive or references to objects.*

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2 };
int i = arr[0];
assert arr instanceof Object; // true
```

`arr` is a reference to an array which has `int` as a element.

> how it was achieved?

`int[]` has it's own class `int[].class` and your `arr` is an instance of that class.

> It was sth like int=>Integer, or int[]=>Integer[] or something else?

`Integer` is not related at all. to convert an `int[]` into an `Integer[]` you have to create a new array and copy every element one by one.

> And by the way, where it resides? In heap or in stack?

You can assume all objects are on the heap. Java 8 can place some objects on the stack using Escape Analysis, however I don't believe it can do this for array types.

`*` the only other type is `void` which is neither a primitive nor a reference. It has a wrapper `Void` but you can't have a field or parameter of type `void`.

Comment: I'll tend to say that primitive type arrays are not managed like any "regular" Object arrays see:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#New_PrimitiveType_Array_routines